# F# covariance and contravariance in records

Tags: f#

I need to describe following relation:

```fs
type FieldDef<'Object, 'Val> { 
    Name: string; 
    Resolve: 'Object -> 'Val 
}

type ObjectDef<'Object> { 
    Name: string; 
    Fields: FieldDef<'Object, _> list 
}

// example usage
type MyRecord = { X: int; Y: string; }

let myRecordDef = {
    Name = "MyRecord"
    Fields = [
        { Name = "x"; Resolve: fun r -> r.X }
        { Name = "y"; Resolve: fun r -> r.Y }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, `_` is not valid in this use case. The second type param of `FieldDef` may vary in this case - in C# we could annotate it as contravariant and bind to type `Object`. How can I achieve similar result in F# without loosing much of type safety?

Comment: Why not just make objectdef take two type variables

Comment: As I've said, second type param may be different, so i.e. Fields should accept both `Field<MyRecord, int>` and `Field<MyRecord, string>`. I've updated the question with example to better describe desired effect.

Comment: I suspect you are sick with no type safety in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As John is saying, if you want to be completely generic, you are stuck with loss of type safety. Your ObjectDef class is then

```
type ObjectDef<'Object> =
    { 
        Name: string; 
        Fields: FieldDef<'Object, obj> list 
    }
```

I don't know "how generic" you need to be. Here's a suggestion where you work with at least some field types explicitly represented: You first define a discriminated union, replacing your completely generic `'Object -> 'Val`:

```
type FieldGetter<'T> = 
    | Int of ('T -> int)
    | String of ('T -> string)
    | AnythingElse of ('T -> obj)
```

Then define a new field definition record, alongside with a couple of handy overloads:

```
type FieldDef2<'Object> =
    { 
        Name: string; 
        Resolve: FieldGetter<'Object>
    }
    static member Create(name, f) = { Name = name; Resolve = Int f }
    static member Create(name, f) = { Name = name; Resolve = String f }
    static member Create(name, f) = { Name = name; Resolve = AnythingElse f }
type ObjectDef2<'Object> =
    { 
        Name: string; 
        Fields: FieldDef2<'Object> list 
    }
```

Your example then turns into:

```
let myRecordDef = {
    Name = "MyRecord"
    Fields = [ FieldDef2<_>.Create("x", fun r -> r.X); 
                FieldDef2<_>.Create("y", fun r -> r.Y) ]
}
```